# Function replace normalizer_normalize PHP?

Tags: php

I can't use Normalizer class on my server.

```
$body = normalizer_normalize($body,Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

So, have any function can do same thing like Normalizer ???

Comment: Server said "Call to undefined function normalizer_normalize()"

Comment: What OS are you using and what version of PHP?

Comment: My server use Linux, my PHP is 5.3. But I'm not system manager, my system manager tried install library of Normalizer but not success :(. That why I had to find a function replace Normalizer :((

Comment: They need to install the `intl` package. Also, please get off PHP5.3 it's dead, very dead.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can implement their own Unicode normalization function. Just follow this simple recipe: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

In other words, get the Intl extension working. Don't try to reimplement Unicode library functions - it's a LOT of work.